# Searching for key words in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, key, words

If I ask a question in Python and the answer is `chicken`, I want to output something related to chicken. And, if the answer is `beef` I want to output something related to beef, dependent on the answer provided.

How could I structure this? Should I have multiple lists with key words and related answers? Newbie.

Comment: Show some example code!

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `dict` of `list`s:

```
import random

similar_words = {
    'chicken': ['poultry', 'wings'],
    'beef': ['cow', 'ground-beef', 'roast-beef', 'steak'],
}

word = raw_input("Enter a word: ").strip()
if word in similar_words:
    print random.choice(similar_words[word])
else:
    print "Not found!"
```

See the Python manual on [Data Structures](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) for more information. Note that I'm also using [`random.choice()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.choice) to select a random item from each list.

Here's the output of it running:

```
$ python words.py
Enter a word: chicken
poultry
$ python words.py
Enter a word: beef
cow
$
```

**Edit**: You were asking in the comments how you could do this if the words were contained inside a whole sentence. Here's one example:

```
words = raw_input("Enter a word or sentence: ").strip().split()

for word in words:
    if word.lower() in similar_words:
        print random.choice(similar_words[word.lower()])
    else:
        print "Not found!"
```

Here, we're using `split()` to split the sentence into a `list` of words. Then we loop through each word, and see if (the lowercase version of) the word exists in our `dict`, and do the same thing as we did above with a single word.

Comment: That's very helpful, thanks. What if want to choose chicken for example but it was in a sentence e.g. are there any chicken recipes. Can pick out the relevant word 'chicken' if it was in a sentence?

Comment: No problem! That would get more complicated. How does the program know which word in the sentence is most important? You could pick a word related to ALL words in the sentence that `similar_words` exist for, though! I'll add a quick edit as an example.